# Most Efficient Version of PLSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, sql-execution-plan

I am writing a PL/SQL stored procedure which will be called from within a .NET application.

My stored procedure must return

- the count of values in a table of part revisions, based on an input part number,
- the name of the lowest revision level currently captured in this table for the input part number
- the name of the revision level for a particular unit in the database associated with this part number and an input unit ID.

  The unit's revision level name is captured within a separate table with no direct relationship to the part revision table.

Relevant data structure:

```
Table Part has columns:
    Part_ID int PK
    Part_Number varchar2(30)

Table Part_Revisions:
    Revision_ID int PK
    Revision_Name varchar2(100)
    Revision_Level int
    Part_ID int FK

Table Unit:
    Unit_ID int PK
    Part_ID int FK

Table Unit_Revision:
    Unit_ID int PK
    Revision_Name varchar2(100)
```

With that said, what is the most efficient way for me to query these three data elements into a ref cursor for output?   I am considering the following option 1:

```
OPEN cursor o_Return_Cursor FOR
SELECT (SELECT COUNT (*)
          FROM Part_Revisions pr
          inner join PART pa on pa.part_id = pr.part_id
         WHERE PA.PART_NO = :1 )
          AS "Cnt_PN_Revisions",
       (select pr1.Revision_Name from Part_Revisions pr1 
            inner join PART pa1 on pa1.part_id = pr1.part_id
            WHERE PA.PART_NO = :1 and pr1.Revision_Level = 0)
          AS "Input_Revison_Level",
       (select ur.Revision_Name from Unit_Revision ur
            WHERE ur.Unit_ID = :2) as "Unit_Revision"
        FROM DUAL;
```

However, Toad's Explain Plan returns Cost:2 Cardinality: 1, which I suspect is due to me using DUAL in my main query.   Comparing that to option 2:

```
select pr.Revision_Name, (select count(*) 
                           from Part_Revisions pr1
                           where pr1.part_id = pr.part_id) as "Count",
                         (select ur.Revision_Name 
                           from Unit_Revision ur
                           where ur.Unit_ID = :2) as "Unit_Revision"
from Part_Revisions pr 
            inner join PART pa on pa.part_id = pr.part_id
            WHERE PA.PART_NO = :1 and pr.Revision_Level = 0
```

Essentially I don't really know how to compare the results from my execution plans, to chose the best design.   I have also considered a version of option 1, where instead of joining twice to the Part table, I select the Part_ID into a local variable, and simply query the Part_Revisions table based on that value.   However, this is not something I can use the Explain Plan to analyze.

Answer (score 1):

Your description and select statements look different... I based the procedure on the SQL statements.

```
PROCEDURE the_proc
(
    part_no_in         IN  NUMBER
,   revision_level_in  IN  NUMBER
,   unit_id_in         IN  NUMBER
,   part_rev_count_out OUT NUMBER
,   part_rev_name_out  OUT VARCHAR2
,   unit_rev_name_out  OUT VARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    INTO    part_rev_count_out
    FROM    part  pa
    WHERE   pa.part_no = part_no_in
    AND     EXISTS
            (
                SELECT  1
                FROM    part_revisions  pr
                WHERE   pa.part_id = pr.part_id
            );

    SELECT  pr1.revision_name 
    INTO    part_rev_name_out
    FROM    part_revisions  pr1
    WHERE   pr1.revision_level = revision_level_in
    AND     EXISTS
            (
                SELECT  1
                FROM    part  pa1
                WHERE   pa1.part_id = pr1.part_id
                AND     pa.part_no = part_no_in
            );

    SELECT  ur.revision_name
    INTO    unit_rev_name_out
    FROM    unit_revision ur
    WHERE   ur.unit_id = unit_id_in;
END the_proc;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are obtaining scalar values. Rather than return a cursor, just return the values using clean sql statements. I have done this numerous times from .net, it works fine.

```
Procedure get_part_info(p_partnum in part.part_number%type
    , ret_count          out integer 
    , ret_revision_level out part_revisions.revision_level%type
    , ret_revision_name  out part_revisions.revision_name%type) as
begin 
   select count(*) into ret_count from ....;
   select min(revision_level) into ret_revision_level from ...;
   select revision_name in ret_revision_name...;
   return;
end;
```